# Disable adding point on zoom button click

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am using leaflet (v. 1.0.2) map with the leaflet.draw (v. 0.2) plugin. I edited control buttons and now when I am trying to add polygon with leaflet.draw and click zoom button it adds the point on map.

How can I disable it?

HTML for the control button:

```
<div class="leaflet-control">
    <a class="leaflet-control-zoom-out btn-floating waves-effect waves-light teal accent-4" href="#" title="Zoom out" role="button" aria-label="Zoom out">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-minus"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of Leaflet are you using? Which web browser? Which input method (mouse, touchscreen)?

Comment: @IvanSanchez I am using Chrome and the method is mouse

Comment: @MMK i do not need to disable zoom, I want the zoom button to work when I click on it while creating a polygon

Comment: @purelistica without code its difficult to assess what you trying to do unfortunately.

Comment: I've put a simple example at https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/jaye/edit?html,output and cannot reproduce the problem. BTW if you gonna use Leaflet.Draw, use v0.4.0 or greater, because that's the first version made to be compatible with Leaflet >= v1.0.0

Comment: @IvanSanchez there is no problem for me either if I use default style buttons, but if I edit them (as above) I get this problem. Maybe there is some class or event that should be added to prevent this?

Comment: @purelistica Please show us a complete example.